# How do I make default settings work for select fields with WordPress API?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

std is the default value of an option if it is not set. I only need the default value for the select fields. I've tried many things but nothing seems to work. I really need help on this. I don't know where to start.

So here, I do my function to add the setting to my options page.

```
                function nl_register_function_name() {
                    // Validation callback
                    register_setting( 'nl_theme_options', 'nl_theme_options', 'nl_validate_settings' );
                    // Add setting to section
                    add_settings_section( 'nl_styling_section', 'Styling', 'nl_display_styling_section', 'nl_theme_options.php' );
                    // Create selection field
                    $field_args = array(
                        'type'      => 'select',
                        'id'        => 'nl_function_name',
                        'name'      => 'nl_function_name',
                        'desc'      => 'Select border bottom size.',
                        'std'       => 'Small',
                        'label_for' => 'nl_function_name',
                        'items'     => array( 
                            "None",
                            "Small",
                            "Medium",
                            "Large"
                        )
                    );
                    // Label
                    add_settings_field( 'label_function_name', 'function_name', 'nl_display_setting', 'nl_theme_options.php', 'nl_styling_section', $field_args );
                }
                // Registers the setting
                add_action( 'admin_init', 'nl_register_function_name' );
```

And here, I create the HTML for the select field.

```
        function nl_display_setting ( $args ) {
            extract( $args );
            $option_name = 'nl_theme_options';
            $options = get_option( $option_name );
            switch ( $args['type'] ) {  
                case 'select':
                    if( isset( $options[$id] ) ) {
                        $options[$id] = stripslashes( $options[$id] );
                        $options[$id] = esc_attr( $options[$id] );
                        echo "<select name='" . $option_name . "[$id]' value='$options[$id]'>";
                        foreach( $items as $item ) {
                            $selected = ($options[$id]==$item) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                            echo "<option value='$item' $selected>$item</option>";
                        }
                    } elseif ( !isset( $options[$id] ) ) {
                        $std = $args['std'];
                        echo "<select name='" . $option_name . "[$id]' value='$std'>";
                        foreach( $items as $item ) {
                            echo "<option value='$item'>$item</option>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    echo ($desc != '') ? "<br><span class='description'>$desc</span>" : "";  
                break;
            }
        }
```

How do I make default settings work for select fields with WordPress API?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it! I'm going to post the solution here for others that might have the same problem in the future because there doesn't seem to be any solution online.

```
                case 'select':
                    if( isset( $options[$id] ) ) {
                        $options[$id] = stripslashes( $options[$id] );
                        $options[$id] = esc_attr( $options[$id] );
                        echo "<select name='" . $option_name . "[$id]' value='$options[$id]'>";
                        foreach( $items as $item ) {
                            $selected = ($options[$id]==$item) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                            echo "<option value='$item' $selected>$item</option>";
                        }
                    } elseif ( !isset( $options[$id] ) ) {
                        echo "<select name='" . $option_name . "[$id]' value='$std'>";
                        foreach( $items as $item ) {
                            $selected = ($std==$item) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                            echo "<option value='$item' $selected>$item</option>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    echo ($desc != '') ? "<br><span class='description'>$desc</span>" : "";  
                break;
```

Comment: +1, totally forgot how procedural spegettieish Wordpress can be